# Django no me muestra un form. Pero antes si lo hacia, dejo de funcionar

Tags: django, formularios

Estoy trabajando con Forms en Django, pero a la hora de querer renderizar un form, no me muestra nada, tengo dos apps diferentes, pero en una si me funciona bien y en la otra no, CABE MENCIONAR QUE SI MOSTRABA TODO CORRECTAMENTE AL PRINCIPIO, el proyecto ya estaba trabajando y dejo de funcionar, no le movi nada al codigo, quise pensar que eran problemas con el explorador, ya borre la cache, instale y reinstale y nada, no se a que se deba.
este es mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de querer agregar en la app de tareas si me muestra el formulario, pero en contactos no me muestra nada :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No somos adivinos, no te podemos apoyar si no compartes el código o un fragmento de este.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.